# When I was running a python file, an error occurred."TypeError: must be real number, not str"

Tags: python

`p1.py`

```py
import sys


def sum(x1, x2):
    return (x1 + x2)


x0 = sys.argv[1]
x1 = sys.argv[2]
x2 = sys.argv[3]
print("user is:" + x0)
print(x1)
print(x2)
print(sum(float(x1), float(x2)))
print("hello world")
```

`p2.py`

```py
import os
import sys

paraA = sys.argv[0]
paraB = sys.argv[1]
paraC = sys.argv[2]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("python p1.py %s %f %f" % (paraA, paraB, paraC))
```

I run the code with:

```
python p2.py 3 6
```

and the error occur:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Why is that? I want to transmit the name of `p2` to `p1.name` is str not number. Why does the error occur?

Answer (score 1):

Error lies in this line;

```
os.system("python p1.py %s %f %f" % (paraA, paraB, paraC))
```

You are not converting the last two into float;

```
os.system("python p1.py %s %f %f" % (paraA, float(paraB), float(paraC)))
```

Answer (score 1):

sys.argv always give you "string", so this line will cause error when you cast a "string"(paraB,paraC) to "%f", which expect a "float".

```
os.system("python p1.py %s %f %f" % (paraA, paraB, paraC))
```

And in your case, instead of using "float(paraB)" in "p2.py", I suggest keeping them as string and make them float in p1.py, which your code already did that. This way you cause less trouble as float(1) will print "1.000000" [with 6 zero as default](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec).

p2.py

```
os.system("python p1.py %s %s %s" % (paraA, paraB, paraC))
```

p1.py

```
...
x1 = sys.argv[2]
x2 = sys.argv[3]
print(sum(float(x1), float(x2)))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv values are considered as string.

Do this :

```
paraB = float(sys.argv[1])
paraC = float(sys.argv[2])
```

Hope it will help you